# Saving occurrences in RegEx and Comparing the counts

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to improve the following line of code

```
//var expr = '0100101011011011';
if ((expr.match(/0/g) || []).length === (expr.match(/1/g) || []).length) {}
```

into a single line of regex, if that's possible.
expr string is a series of 0s and 1s. I just need to check
if the string has an equal number of 0s and 1s. Any idea?
I just want to see if it's possible, not necessarily improve...

Comment: I don't think that "[doing all] into a single regex" is the way to go to improve your code.

Comment: `expr.split(0).length == expr.split(1).length`?

Comment: in regular expression

Comment: it can be done with .net regex: `^(?:0(?<c>)|1(?<-c>))*$(?(c)(?!))` (test it with http://regexstorm.net) but not sure if a workaround is possible in javascript.